# Where is argument read by Python parse_args?

Tags: python

I want to call a Python module from the command line to convert a time in my timezone to UTC time like this:

```
$ dt-la-utc.py "2017-10-14 12:10:00"
```

When I execute the module shown below, the convert_la_utc function works correctly if I hard-code the date and time.  However, I want to feed it the date and time as input on the command line.  But the parse_args function isn't working.  If I run the Python debugger and examine the "args" variable, there's nothing in it.  What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import argparse
import datetime
from pdb import set_trace as debug
import pytz
import sys

def parse_args():
    """Parse arguments."""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Convert LA time to UTC time.")
    parser.add_argument("dt", help="LA date and time in format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    debug()
    return args

def convert_la_utc():
    """Convert time in Los Angeles to UTC time."""
    date = '2017-10-12'
    time = '20:45:00'
    date_time = date + ' ' + time
    datetime_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

    local = pytz.timezone("America/Los_Angeles")
    naive = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time, datetime_format)
    local_dt = local.localize(naive, is_dst=None)
    utc_dt = local_dt.astimezone(pytz.utc)
    print "Datetime in Los Angeles: {0}".format(date_time)
    print "UTC equivalent datetime: {0}".format(utc_dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

def main():
    args = parse_args()
    convert_la_utc()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to further retrieve your argument, for example:

```
def main():
    args = parse_args()
    dt = args.dt
```

What `parser.parse_args()` returns is an `argparse.Namespace` object - you can verify it by adding `print type(args)` in your `def main()`. More explanation can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args).

Comment: That's not it.  If it's not visible inside the function, it's not going to be visible outside it.

Comment: try to print args.dt just after having parsed it. it works. argparser defines dynamic members from the name of your option.